# Обновление даты в программе

Tags: c#

Пишу свой первый проект на C# (парсер валют) и появилась загвоздка. Через функцию DateTime хочу получать дату нового дня, но запрос новой даты мне нужен раз в сутки. Возможно ли получать новую дату только если она изменилась и как? Может есть функция для проверки этого условия?

Также я хочу заносить даты в массив. Тогда какой лучше использовать string или object?

Comment: А как вы собираетесь хранить данные?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то идея пока что такая - даты я хочу заносить в массив (дня 4 примерно), при каждом обновлении даты делать сдвиг и записывать туда же, но на новое место.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Возможно ли получать новую дату только если она изменилась и как?

Можно, и специальная функция тут не нужна, обычное сравнение.

```
DateTime savedDate;
if (savedDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date)
    savedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

> Также я хочу заносить даты в массив. Тогда какой лучше использовать string или object?

Ни тот, ни другой. Храните в виде `List<DateTime>`, если нужны только даты, либо 
`Dictionary<DateTime, YourLinkedDataClass>`, если к каждой дате привязаны какие-то данные описываемые `YourLinkedDataClass`. В последнем случае нужно учесть что `Dictionary<Tkey, TValue>` требует уникальность ключа и не для каждой задачи подходит.

Comment: List<DateTime> если я  не ошибаюсь, это же массив по-сути? Если нет, то как из него получать значение даты, например вторую по счету, записанную туда?

Comment: также как из массива, по индексу

Comment: Ясно, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @fearyt98 List по большому счету и есть массив, только с кучей дополнительных методов.